# Nginx, charset directive not working when sending 301 redirect

Tags: nginx

I have set the charset to 'utf-8' in the nginx.conf file under the `http` directive. It looks like this:

```
http {
  charset utf-8;
}
```

I have two server directives. One for example.com, and one for www.example.com. They look like this.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location /{
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

However, an initial request to `example.com` does not seem to present the charset type after the `Content-Type` HTTP header. Here are the response headers:

```
$ curl example.com -I --progress-bar
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 05:10:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.example.com/

$ curl www.example.com -I --progress-bar
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 05:13:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 123
Last-Modified: Tue, 08 Jul 2014 00:55:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "53bb418a-7b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Why isn't the charset being set in the non-www server?

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not define custom error page for 301 error, nginx sends it's built-in special page with predefined headers.

See https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c#L646

Comment: And it really doesn't matter since almost nobody will ever see that bit of HTML anyway.

Comment: 301 is not an error. I'm sorry but your answer does not make sense. I do not why you got an up-vote.

Comment: It's not an error, but you could define custom page for 301 code with `error_page` directive. By default nginx sends its own page with this exact headers.

Comment: And why do you ever bother this?